# how to use neo4j to handle one to many relationship, filter and sort

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have mysql DB like below:

```
user
- id
- createDate

user_attribute
- id
- name

user_user_attribute
- userId
- attId
- value
```

And now, I changed these three table into neo4J node and relationship as below:

```
node_user:
- id
- createDate
node_user_attribue:
- id
- name
relationship:
- startingNode: user
- endingNode: attribute
- value
```

So now, what I want is to list all the users, I can use below:

```
match (u:User)-[uua:USER_USER_ATTRIBUTE]->(ua:UserAttribute)
return u.id, collect(ua.name), collect(uua.value)
```

the above query is returning below:

```
12345, [att1, att2, att3], [att1_value, att2_value, att3_value]
```

But now, the problem comes:

how can I filter and sort by some particular attribute value, for example, I want to filter out all the users having attr1 to be 'value1'

```
match (u:User)-[uua:USER_USER_ATTRIBUTE]->(ua:UserAttribute)
where uua.value="216.144.237.76"
return u.id, collect(ua.name), collect(uua.value)
```

but unfortunately, the result is only like below:

```
12345, ['ip'], ['216.144.237.76]
```

This is not what I need, what I need is all the user having ip as 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx', and also return all the user attributes instead of only IP attribute

Also, how can I order by one field inside the the collection fields? For example, how can I order by ip

I don't know if my requirement is clear here, and hope to hear your advice.

Thanks

```
using With doesn't make any difference:
match (u:User)-[uua:USER_USER_ATTRIBUTE]->(ua:UserAttribute)
where uua.value="216.144.237.76"
with u, ua
return u.id, collect(ua.name)
```

now I only have:

```
uid, ["ip]
```

I believe whenever I put where for one relationship, ONLY that particular relationship value will be found, not all the user's relationship will be found. Seemed I have to modify the data schema here.

Comment: maybe you should use the keyword "**with**" to aggregate the results. 

    match (u:User)-[uua:USER_USER_ATTRIBUTE]->(ua:UserAttribute)
    where uua.value="216.144.237.76" with u, ua
    return u.id, collect(ua.name)

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't model this as attributes on a :User node, or as separate types of nodes (like :IPAddress) with their own values?

Comment: the reason is our current MYSQL db is many to many with join table in the middle. So when I use load csv command, this solution is by default. If I move all the attribute into :User node, that will make :user node very big and also the simple load csv command can not be used anymore.